# Dynamically created sql not happy

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains records of a 'widget' many of the columns contain just the Id of a record in a different table. When editing the widget record users are allowed to do a save even if it is incomplete. They can open it later and continue. 
The problem I have, is when it is incomplete my query returns nothing because the where clause contain fields which have default 0 in them and there is no match in the other tables. Here is a sample of script which illustrates this problem.

```
select Client,Make,Model,Shape
from
widget,clients,makes,models,shapes
where 
widget.ClientId = '3' and
widget.MakeId = makes.Id and
widget.ModelId = models.Id and
widget.ShapeId = shapes.Id
```

I am building this query dynamically using PHP so am trying to keep it as simple as possible. All sugestions welcome, thanks.

Comment: IMHO you need to use `JOIN` statements to be able to aggregate your tables like that.

Comment: This is a basic question that can be answered in any introductory guide to sql.

Comment: @Strawberry, I don't know... Queries' happiness and wellbeing are not addressed often enough in technical literature in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an implicit `inner join` (implicit meaning that you do the join in the `where` clause). Inner joins return matching records only, therefore if some of the data are incomplete, no records will be returned.

Use an `outer join` instead, that return all records from one of the tables in the join and the matching records from the other table (MySQL does not support full outer join, but this is not relevant here anyway).

Based on your description `widget` table is your main table, so use `left join` to join all other tables on `widget` to get the widget even if it is incomplete:

```
select c.Client, m.make, md.model, s.shape
from widget w
left join clients c on c.id = w.ClientId
left join makes m on m.id = w.MakeId
left join models md on md.id = w.ModelId
left join shapes s on s.id = w.ShapeId
```

Comment: Thank you. I had original tried join but without the left :(

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.Client, m.make, md.model, s.shape
from widget w
join clients c on c.id = w.ClientId
join makes m on m.id = w.MakeId
join models md on md.id = w.ModelId
join shapes s on s.id = w.ShapeId
```

Use Joins instead of multiple tables in FROM Clause.

Comment: A simple inner join will not do (in MySQL join is equivalent to inner join).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of direct join use `LEFT JOIN` so that no matter if there is records from other tables, still first table entries will be returned:

```
SELECT Client, Make, Model, Shape
FROM widget
LEFT JOIN clients ON widget.ClientId = widget.Id
LEFT JOIN makes ON widget.MakeId = makes.Id
LEFT JOIN models ON widget.ModelId = models.Id
LEFT JOIN shapes ON widget.ShapeId = shapes.Id
WHERE widget.ClientId = 3
```

---

Table columns should be in lower case

---

Table names should be in singular form, e.g. `model`, `shape`

---

Foreign keys should be in other table. Instead of `widget` having `ModelId`, `model` should have `widget` id

*I may be wrong if relations are different*

Comment: "Foreign keys should be in other table." ? A single widget could be one of many models. It looks up the model description  in the model table. The id come from a drop downlist on the form